# How to create Spring Security 3.1 Datasource bean in a java class

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-bean

I am new to JSF and Spring Security.
I am building a JSF 2 project based on [this tutorial](http://mprabhat.com/2012/07/11/spring-security-3-1-and-jsf-2-0-custom-form/). I want to put the dataSource bean in a java class because I am generating the url for the JDBC connection and users in another class.
How to put this code from my security-config.xml to a java class.

```
 <beans:bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <beans:property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/spring_security_db" />
    <beans:property name="username" value="root" />
    <beans:property name="password" value="" />
 </beans:bean>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a new Class which implements DriverManagerDataSource whith is's constructor and then in your beans definiton in the class tag put the name of that Class.
Your Class something like this:

```
package dao; 
public class dataSource extends DriverManagerDataSource { 
 public dataSource() { 
 // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub 
  this.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
  this.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://.../....."); 
  this.setUsername(""); this.setPassword(""); 
   }
}
```

Your bean definition like that:

```
<beans:bean id="dataSource" class="dao.dataSource">
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use Spring's [expression language](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-beandef-xml-based). You can specify a method call to retrieve, for example, the url parameter:

```
<beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <beans:property name="url" value="#{someOtherBean.someMethod()}" />
    <beans:property name="username" value="root" />
    <beans:property name="password" value="" />
</beans:bean>
```

You would need to define the other bean whose method you are referencing. The programmatic approach would be something like this:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;

@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public DriverManagerDataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/spring_security_db");
        dataSource.setUsername("root");
        dataSource.setPassword("");

        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

In your Spring config you would need to specify component scan with the appropriate package to pick up the bean:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="yourpackage.configpackage"/>          

</beans>
```